# Catching Exceptions from an Event Handler from another class

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have the following snippet from Class A where I am performing an Async action on a database and subscribe to the InfoMessage event handler to catch informational messages from SQL.

```
public void BackupDatabase(string DatabaseName, string BackupLocation, bool backupType = true)
    {
        //SQL for FULL database backup
        string SQL = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + DatabaseName + "] TO  DISK = N'" + BackupLocation + "\\" + DatabaseName +".bak' WITH FORMAT,  NAME = N'" + DatabaseName + "-Full Database Backup', STATS = 1";

        using (SqlConnection db_conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            UpdateStatusText("Establishing Connection to Database");
            db_conn.Open();
            db_conn.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true;
            db_conn.InfoMessage += BackupInfoMessages;

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, db_conn))
            {

                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            UpdateStatusText("Backup Complete.");
        }
    }

    private void BackupInfoMessages(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (SqlError info in e.Errors)
        {
            if(info.Class > 10)
            {
                logFile.ExMsg("Exception : " + e.Message);
                throw new Exception(e.Message);

            }
            else
            {
                UpdateStatusText(e.Message, 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

In Class B, I am using a backgroundworker which uses an instance of Class A to run "BackupDatabase" in a try catch

```
try 
{
   DBOperations.BackupDatabase("DB","C:\\DBBackup\\DB.bak");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

  logFile.ExMsg(ex.Message);
  logFile.ExMsg(ex.StackTrace);
  /* additional code to stop bgWorker */

 }
```

Depending on the severity level of the message reported from SQL, I will handle it accordingly, whenever an exception is thrown from there, the BackgroundWorker is not catching the exception thrown from ClassA.BackupInfoMessages... I have tried moving around my try/catch block and adding one in the BackupDatabase method with no luck. It seems to just skip it and treat it as if no Exception was thrown. The debugger in VS shows that a System.Exception was thrown but nothing is affected. Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I switched out for the ExecuteNonQuery(). Thanks for the help!

Comment: I deleted my answer seeing that the calling code really should have caught the exception. That you see it in VS but it's not being caught in the calling method is weird...have to think abut that :-|

Comment: One thing you might try is NOT catching the exception in the background worker, but deal with it in the worker's RunWorkerCompleted event. With multiple threads in play, this may be the more appropriate way to catch it.

Comment: How would I go about handling it in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event? Removing the try/catch block does nothing and still returns as if it ran correctly, despite the debugger showing exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to think of `BackupInfoMessages` as running in it's own seperate background worker, that is why the try/catch does to catch it, because the event is not in the same call stack as your try/catch block.

You will need some other way than directly raising a exception to convey that an error happened.

I think, but am not 100% sure, that anything error level 11 or higher will make ExecuteNonQuery throw an exception with the error info in it so you may not need to raise the exception manually in your event handler. However setting `.FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true` may change that behavior.

Comment: I don't know a good alternative way to show the error info off of the top of my head, but if I think of one I will update my answer with a example.

Comment: You are right in that setting the `.FireInfoMessageEventOnuserErrors` to false (or removing it) will throw an exception and partially solves my issue. On the other hand, I have no way of reporting progress of the Backup to the user without InfoMessages being sent from SQL.

Comment: I resorted to simply assigning a public boolean to check if the process failed and tested against the severity level of SQL messages and switch the boolean accordingly, and then test the boolean after the query completed and finally throw an exception from BackupDatabase depending on the result.

Comment: @ephtee have you considered [using SMO to do the backup operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.sqlbackup.aspx)? It has a [PercentComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backuprestorebase.percentcomplete.aspx) event you can listen to.

Comment: I have looked into that, however would the target machine that the program runs on require any sort of prerequisite to run the commands? Such as Management Studio pre-installed?

Comment: You would need to include the SMO redistibutables. Go [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16978) then in the "install instructions section" the MSI's you would include in your installer are in the "Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Shared Management Objects" scetion